# how to write an email as hyperlink to a cell when user click on link open outlook phpexcel?

Tags: hyperlink, phpexcel

I used phpexcel to generate report i wrote to a column name of people then i want to add their email as hyper link, to open outlook when use click on names. for any guide to do this one thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty easy: it's simply a `mailto` hyperlink

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('E27', 'Send E-Mail');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('E27')
    ->getHyperlink()
    ->setUrl('mailto:support@phpexcel.net?Subject=Support%20Request');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('E27')
    ->getHyperlink()
    ->setTooltip('Send E-Mail to support team');
```